# ajax calls scrambling iterator value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, iterator

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to the Wikipedia API, looping through results received from a previous call to the Wikipedia API.

```
var intro = [];

for (var i in json.query.search) {
      (function(i) {
        $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&list=&meta=&titles=" + link[i] + "&callback=?&exsentences=1&exintro=1", function(data) {
          for (var key in data.query.pages) {
            var temp = data.query.pages[key].extract;
            intro.push(temp);
            break;
          }
          console.log(intro);
          $('#results-div').append("<div class='col-xs-12'><a target='_blank' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + link[i] + "'><div class='result-inner'><h2 class='text-center'>" + pageTitle[i] + "</h2>" + intro[i] + "</div></a></div>");
        });
      })(i);
    }
```

getJSON does not go through the results in order (the value of i, if called within getJSON's success function, goes in a random order from 0-10, while if it's called outside of it, it will go from 0-10 in order). As a result, the appended values are not in the correct order.

Not only that, the `intro` array populated by data from getJSON does not always correspond to the values of the `link` and `pageTitle` arrays (which correspond to each other). This is the `i` value used by getJSON isn't the same as the one currently being iterated in the loop. e.g. while i starts at 0, getJSON's first call may use 5 as `i`.

How can I get getJSON to use the proper iterator value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can force getJSON to create an object with keys in a specific order, but you can write your own for loop where you control the order of iteration:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.query.pages.length; j++) {
  var temp = data.query.pages[j].extract;
  intro.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, since I specifically need to make a second, different call in order to get the values for *intro*